# Unity3d CharacterController Collider is not moving with the Player Mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, collider, mesh-collider

i added a charactercontroller to my Player Mesh but for some reason the CharacterController is not moving with the Player Mesh.

here's the code for character movements

```
    // Vars
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float walkSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float runSpeed;

    private Vector3 moveDirection;
    private Vector3 velocity;

    [SerializeField] private bool isGrounded;
    [SerializeField] private float groundCheckDistance;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundMask;
    [SerializeField] private float gravity;

    [SerializeField] private float jumpHeight;

    // Ref
    private CharacterController controller;
    private Animator anim;

    private void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        anim = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Move();
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            StartCoroutine(Attack());
        }
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, groundCheckDistance, groundMask);


        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        float moveZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float moveY = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        moveDirection = new Vector3(moveY, 0, moveZ);
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);


        if (isGrounded)
        {
            if (moveDirection != Vector3.zero && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                Walk();
            }
            else if (moveDirection != Vector3.zero && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                Run();
            }
            else if (moveDirection == Vector3.zero)
            {
                Idle();
            }

            moveDirection *= moveSpeed;

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                Jump();
            }

        }

        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void Idle()
    {
        anim.SetFloat("Speed", 0, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);

    }
    private void Walk()
    {
        moveSpeed = walkSpeed;
        anim.SetFloat("Speed", 0.5f, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);

    }
    private void Run()
    {
        moveSpeed = runSpeed;
        anim.SetFloat("Speed", 1f, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
    }
    private void Jump()
    {
        velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2 * gravity);
    }

    private IEnumerator Attack()
    {
        anim.SetLayerWeight(anim.GetLayerIndex("Attack Layer"), 1);
        anim.SetTrigger("Attack");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.9f);
        anim.SetLayerWeight(anim.GetLayerIndex("Attack Layer"), 0);
    }
```

[A picture for the CharacterController and Player Mesh Before I Start and Move-in

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3jzh.png [1]

[And That's after I enter game mode and move] game]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg1g7.png [2]

Comment: Is Player Mesh child of your Player transform? Or is it separated? If it is, then it won't move along with your Player transform.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the player mesh is separated from the player GameObject (and therefore the character controller). Make sure that it's parented so that the transforms move together.

Comment: I made sure that they are not separated, still getting the same results.